# Evaluate Arithmetic and Save as Variable in For Loop

Tags: for-loop, variables, math, zsh

I am trying to set variables in a `for loop` that will be used to evaluate mathematical equations and then be used to modify row values of a tsv using `awk`.  The variables do not need to persist outside of the for loop and it is okay that they are overwritten with each iteration of the loop.  I am a novice and I've cobbled together other forum answers to make this code: please point out if there is a better way to do something like this.

My code currently fails at the `awk` step

2. awk produces an output file, but it is empty.  The command line doesn't complete, as if it is waiting for additional code.

```
for file in *.tsv
do
  declare -i A=$(wc -l < $file) ;
  print $A ;
  declare -i B=$A/10 ;
  print $B ;
  awk -v B="$B" 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
  {$2 = $2/(B); print}' $file > example.tsv
done
```

Comment: In `declare -i B=$($A/10) ;` what is `$A`? Are you expecting to executa a command named `what_$A_expands_to/10`?

Comment: I'm running on Linux/macOS.  I run the shell through terminal.  $A is the number of rows of the TSV, defined by `declare -i A=$(wc -l < $file)`

Comment: What are you expecting `declare -i B=$($A/10) ;` to do? In bash `$(...)` executes the command `...` which means there must be a command named `$A/10` (where `$A` is expanded) for it to succeed . Not sure about `zsh`.

Comment: /bin/zsh Didn't know there was a difference between shell and zsh.

Comment: `zsh` is just one of many shells.

Comment: `declare -i B=$($A/10)` I want to set the variable B as the numerical value of A/10.  So if A was 50, B=5 (50/10)

Comment: Ok, and do you have a she-bang at the top of the script? `#!/bin/...` something? In `bash` you'd do `declare -i B=$((A/10))` and then if `$A` is `50`, `B` would become `5`.

Comment: You're right.  I was incorrectly using $.  `declare -i B=$A/10 ;` does what I want.  The awk portion still fails

Comment: *The awk portion still fails*. Better to show the actual results o "failure". Also, we need to see one line of data **edited into the body of your question** (not a comment). (Is it failing on the text header?) . Good luck.

Comment: I updated the question.  I wasn't sure if that was appropriate, as there is no way for me to give Ted credit for his help solving the first issue now...

Comment: *"The command line doesn't complete, as if it is waiting for additional code."* It's waiting for a filename to be specified (or for you to manually type data via keyboard to the stdin, concluded with Ctrl-D to close the stream).   The std pattern is `awk -v x="y" '{code}' file > outputFile`. Good luck!

Comment: *no way for me to give Ted credit* . Readers that reply on comments just want to help you close what is often a duplicate question. If he writes a full answer, then you can upvote any answer that helps you AND you can accept one answer as the one that really answered your quetion.

Comment: @JVGen You may write up an answer and answer your own question if you'd like. That may help others with similar questions in the future so that's encouraged.